# Report Viewer inaccessible due to protection level

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I get this error when passing my TextBox value to my Crystal Report. How can I resolve this?

> Error 1   'Project.Print1.crystalReportViewer1' is inaccessible due to its protection level   C:\Users\Yourlaks\Desktop\U1\Project\Project\Callcul.cs 307 16  Project

This code gets the values from my textboxes to be shown in the report, including the error line:

```
private void buttonX3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Print1 pr = new Print1();
    CrystalReport1 cr1 = new CrystalReport1();
    TextObject to1 = (TextObject)cr1.ReportDefinition.Sections["Section4"].ReportObjects["Txt1"];
    to1.Text = textBoxX1.Text;
    pr.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr1;
    pr.Show();
}
```